# advanced custom fields for page templates

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, advanced-custom-fields

Wordpress ACF -> querying page templates instead of posts.

So basically I have setup advanced custom fields and I want to structure my website so that when I create a page with a page template of, say, 'topic-page' I would like ACF to add the custom fields to all pages that have a page template of 'topic-page'.

In the past I would use the `$args` array to query the `post_type = 'slug'`; however, how do I query a page template?

Existing code for querying post types:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' = 'the name of the post type' ); $args = new WP_Query( $args );
```

So I would like to modify it to be able to reference fields from a page template.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To query pages you can set the post_type to 'page':

```
'post_type' => 'page'
```